# Default params in method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to add some default params to my method if the user does not set them:

```
public function article($articleId, $userId = 1){
```

The above works, but I wish to replace $userId from Auth

```
public function article($articleId, $userId = Auth::id()){
```

But I get the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cant use a function or method call as a default value of a function parameter.

This should work though:

```
public function article($articleId, $userId = NULL){
    if(!is_numeric($userId) || empty($userId)) $userId = Auth:id();
    //OTHER THINGS HERE
}
```

Comment: The only concern that I'd have is if the user ID is 0; the empty call would return true in that case. However, I think that auto-incremented values start with 1 (and not 0), so this would work if userID is driven from an auto-incremented value

Comment: There's a multitude of things that could cause this to be wrong, but that would all go into the IF statement and doesn't necessarily invalidate my answer.

Comment: that seems to fit better, this is the validation I'd use.

Comment: ID's don't necessarily need to be numeric.

Comment: This is true, but how often are they really not?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do it like this:

```
public function article($articleId, $userId = null){
    if(!is_int($userId)){
        $userId = Auth::id();
    }
}
```

If it doesn't have to be an integer:

```
public function article($articleId, $userId = null){
    if(is_null($userId)){
        $userId = Auth::id();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same comment, ID's don't necessarily need to be numeric.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a class member or a function call

So, you have to set your default value in implementation of your method

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this.

I guess you should include a public var called $user inside your class (MyClass);

`public $user`;

then:

```
    $c = new MyClass();
    $c->user = $myUser;
    $c->article($article->id);
```

after this, your method will be like this:

```
    public function article($articleId){
        $userId = $this->user->id;
    }
```